# grep - how many patterns at maximum

Tags: grep

I want to use grep in PHP in an anagram search.
I have a wordlist with 600.000 lines of single words (German words).

Now I want to input 7 letters (e.g. ABCDEFG), make all 5040 permutations with them (its 7!) and feed each mostly senseless anagram possibility (e.g. ABCDEFG, ABCDEGF, ABCDGEF, ...) into grep, to check if that word is in my list.

I run it on a Ubuntu 22.04 server with 16 GB RAM, PHP 8.0 and Apache 2.4.

Is it the best way to add all 5040 anagrams as patterns?
E.g.:

```
shell_exec( 'grep "^ABCDEFG$\|^ABCDEGF$\|..." /path/to/wordlist.txt');
```

Is that good practice?
Or would it be better to use a for next loop with 5040 single grep calls and always only one pattern?

I read that grep could take as many patterns as I want but I didn't find any code where there would be as many patterns as in my approach.
I guess the maximum is limited by server capabilities but I didn't test that yet. I don't want to slow down the server too much.

Or is my approach not that good at all and best practice would be totally different?

I tried to use sqlite and used the wordlist in a sqlite DB (with OR for each word) but this takes much too long, it's not possible.

Thanks for hints.

Comment: Pipe `grep` to `grep` to `grep`… Find a pattern that matches 7-letter words. Find a pattern that matches words with the first letter of the set. Find a pattern that matches words with the second letter of the set… Letters that must appear more than once require special treatment. For a 7-letter word there will be at most 8 patterns, I think.

Comment: Or `grep -E '^[ABCDEFG]{7}$'` and then filter out entries with duplicate letters.

Comment: Ahh, no brute-force method, but a logical way - good idea! Thank!

Comment: @StephenKitt's approach is a good one....but why fork grep when PHP already has the ability to open ([fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)) and read files (e.g. [fgets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), and to perform regex matches on strings (e.g. [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php))?   BTW, remember that `shell_exec()` can be extremely dangerous when run with user-supplied arguments....never trust data supplied by users.

Comment: BTW, you might find it useful to do a [search for anagram algorithms](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=anagram+algorithms&ia=answer) or read throgh Rosetta Code's [anagrams](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Anagrams) page.   Finding anagrams has been a very popular & fun programming project since the very earliest days of programming.

Comment: Also, consider whether you will handle accents and character encoding eg utf-8 or latin-15.

Comment: I tracked back an answer on another forum, about searching for FASTA (gene sequences).

It used GNU/awk, and had a pattern of over 500,000 chars (2000 patterns of 250 chars each). It managed to search a test file of 4.5 MB for those patterns in under a second.

One issue is that the standard pattern match (DFA) is pathologically bad in this situation. DFA stands for Deterministic Finite Automaton.

This should be disabled by setting an environment variable before you invoke GNU/awk, like:  `time GAWK_NO_DFA=1 awk ...  `

Comment: Thank you @cas I checked one answer which uses prime numbers and this could be a really sophisticated solution, I could save the prime product into the DB and still use sqlite mostly.

Comment: That solution with prime numbers (from @brandonskerritt51 "An Algorithm for Finding Anagrams" at https://hackernoon.com/an-algorithm-for-finding-anagrams-2fe7655de85b) has a bit of an inconvenience: to build the factor of maybe 7 letters, each representing a single prime number, this gives numbers of trillions high! Even when using the little prime numbers for the most used letters. I would need 29 prime numbers (up to 107). So e.g. bigint type is far too small to save the factor. But the idea is nice!

Answer (score 1):

Since anagrams don't care about the order of the letters, it might make sense for us to also ignore that. Instead, count the number of each letter in the word to be tested, or even more simply, sort the letters of the word. If the counts or the sorted string match the counts or the sorted version of the key string, then you have an anagram.

A simple one-liner solution can be written in Perl. Take the following input file:

```
% cat test.txt
manbat
bantam
hello
```

Then this should print the lines which when sorted contain "aabmnt":

```
% perl -lne 'chomp; print if join("", sort split //, $_) eq "aabmnt"' test.txt
manbat
bantam
```

The `join("", sort split //, $_)` takes the current line `$_`, separates the characters, sorts them and joins them up again.

Or a bit more usefully, sort the key word within the script too, this should give the anagrams of `batman`, the key word to be looked for is passed through the environment:

```
% key=batman perl -lne 'chomp; print if join("", sort split //, $_) eq join("", sort split //, $ENV{key})' test.txt
manbat
bantam
```

Comment: I don't use Perl, but the idea is good! I created a new list from my original wordlist where I can lookup very fast with grep, if my (sorted) search letters are present. I made the file with this command: while read -r line; do echo "$line" | grep -o . | sort | tr -d "\n" >> words_sorted.txt; echo "" >> words_sorted.txt ; done < words.txt

Comment: But I have yet no good idea how I could use wildcards (jokers) with that. E.g.: AFS? (?=Joker) should find FAST. One joker is easy with a loop and  two jokers would need a second loop and e.g. 21 loop rounds with 7 letters (5+2Jokers). Maybe there is a more sophisticated way, which I don't see?